# Is there an official list of Disney Princesses?

Tags: disney, disney-princess

Some characters in Disney movies are labelled as Princesses. Is there an official list of these Princesses? Rules to qualify, requirements that must be met?

[image]

Comment: Even this picture is not complete, missing eg [Sofia the First](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sofia_the_First). So I think any list will keep growing as new princesses are added.

Comment: @Wikis while Sofia the First might be a princess, she is not part of the official product line of Disney Princesses.

Comment: There's also [the Rejected Princesses site,](http://www.rejectedprincesses.com/) if you want an alternative view.

Comment: Is this even ontopic? :)

Comment: @DVK of course disney princesses are on topic!!!!

Comment: Please, Lord. Never allow my 3 year old daughter to see this question. Ever. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget Leia.  And Lilandra, princess of the Shi'ar!

Comment: How about the selection of the princesses for Kingdom Hearts?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Disney Princess is a group created by Andy Mooney to market Disney products to girls.

> Soon after joining Disney, Mooney attended his first "Disney On Ice" show. While waiting in line, he found himself surrounded by young girls dressed as princesses. "They weren't even Disney products. They were generic princess products," he mused. Soon after realizing the demand, the Disney Princess line was formed. - [Disney Wiki](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Disney_Princess#History)

**How they were chosen:**

> The franchise currently comprises eleven female protagonists from ten different Walt Disney Animation Studios films and one Pixar film who are either royal by birth, royal by marriage, or considered a "princess" due to their significant portrayal of heroism in their film.
>
> The characters were not chosen specifically for their royal titles, but rather for how well they fit into what Disney executives deemed "the Princess mythology". Mulan is an example of this concept; she has no familial ties to royalty, but is still included in the character list. Tinker Bell was once included under the same principle before it was decided that she was not suited for the "mythology". - [Disney Wiki](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Disney_Princess)

*Significant portrayal of heroism* is good enough to earn the title of princess.

**Who is included:**

> The original Disney Princess line-up featured **Snow White, Cinderella, Aurora, Ariel, Belle, Jasmine, Pocahontas** and **Mulan**. It later expanded to include **Tiana**, **Rapunzel** and **Merida** after the successes of their respective films. Princess Moana, the star of Disney's upcoming feature Moana, of 2016, is expected to join the line-up. - [Disney Wiki](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Disney_Princess)

Apparently Princess Anna and Queen Elsa (Frozen) aren't good enough for this list.

**Princess Claim to Royalty:**

- Snow White - birth
- Cinderella - marriage
- Aurora - birth
- Ariel - birth
- Belle - marriage
- Jasmine - birth
- Pocahontas - birth+
- Mulan - significant portrayal of heroism
- Tiana - marriage
- Rapunzel - birth
- Merida - birth

+*[Indian Princess](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Pocahontas_(character)#Trivia)*

Comment: __They need to be the main and leading character in the movie__ that is not a sequel; and its speculated that they need to show significant growth/achievement (this is where 'significant portrayal of heroism in their film' comes from) . Elsa is not the main character of Frozen and Anna experiences no character development in the movie.

Comment: the frozen girls didnt cut it, dang!

Comment: Ariel seems to be missing from the claim list...

Comment: @Lan or... Frozen makes more money in merchandise than the rest of the Disney Princess line combined so they're in no hurry to lump them together? :)

Comment: This holiday season, Target was selling a boxed set of princesses that included the two from Frozen.  [The box](http://www.fabulesslytarget.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/1610854_789275731146018_6900457501116094359_n1.jpg) did separate them out as if they were a "bonus", but at least they were sold together...

Comment: @JPhi1618 even the box art separates them.

Comment: @Lan Jasmine wasn't the main character in Aladdin (though she was a strong supporting character)

Comment: @Lan according to praxis's answer on my follow up wuestion anna from frozen is slated to join the official lineup

Comment: Princess Leia Organa of Alderaan belongs in there.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Perhaps, but she isn't there yet.

Comment: How about the selection of the princesses for Kingdom Hearts?

Comment: @izkata Jasmine has a primary (leading) role in Aladdin.

Comment: According to [the trailer for _Ralph Breaks the Internet_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BcYBFC6zfY); Vanellope von Schweetz should be included from now on.

Comment: Disney Princess is a marketing term and group of characters, and is not inclusive of all characters who qualify as a princess.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy-So, does Shuri from Black Panther

Comment: Currently missing Moana.

Answer (score 1):

Jack covers nicely that **Yes, of course there is an official list**. This is Disney after all, one of the most successful companies in recent history if not all time.

I would like to add that there is more to the "How" the Princess are selected...

First you need to meet **all** three of these criteria:

1. Primary Role in an *animated* Disney movie.
2. Human
3. Not primarily star in sequel (i.e. not introduced)

Next you need to meet **one** of the following criteria:

1. Born Royal
2. Marry Royal
3. Perform an act of heroism (aka the Mulan Rule)

Now of course there are many who meet these requirements but [did not make the cut](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112666/which-disney-princesses-did-not-make-the-cut?noredirect=1&lq=1) to be a "Disney Princess". That is be because the final, unwritten criteria is *box office success*.

Comment: This doesn't explain why Princess Anna has been excluded... She meets all the criteria in spades

Comment: @Valorum I did not realize that was part of the question here?

Comment: But the answer, and I think was pointed out on the other question... "Disney Frozen" is its own franchise now, independent of the "Disney Princess" line, much like Tinkerbell is now the "Disney Fairies" line.

Comment: If you make a blanket statement, it probably helps to explain why certain edge cases don't fit. If x = y then z (***unless x = a***).

Comment: Like, *The Black Cauldron* wasn't abig hit, so no Eilonwy. (Also, I'm not sure if that was a licensed work, which might limit things).