# Which Disney Princesses did not make the cut?

Tags: disney, disney-princess

We know from the answers here [Is there an official list of Disney Princesses?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112663/is-there-an-official-list-of-disney-princesses) that some princess dont make it onto the Official list. Which Princesses in Disney movies are NOT official Disney Princesses, and are there reasons why?

Comment: See http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Disney_Princess#Unofficial_Princesses

Comment: I would conjecture that the reasons will all boil down to "merchandising profit" if we look hard enough

Comment: i only think there are maybe 5 ish princess's not on the list, also the frozen girls arnt on the good list and they are most profitable!

Comment: TBH both questions are open-ended lists, but the pace is rather slow, so I think we'll be ok. And "merchandising profit" works both ways: excluded because there's no profit in including them, or excluded because there's *more* profit in keeping them separate.

Comment: How about the selection of the princesses for Kingdom Hearts?

Comment: Any list that doesn't include Kuzco is an incomplete list

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [Disney Wikia](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Disney_Princess) maintains a pretty solid (and ongoing updated) answer to this very question.

The Official [Disney Princess](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Disney_Princess) lineup doesn't include a number of bona-fide princesses who've appeared in animated feature films released by Walt Disney Studios;

- **Queen (formerly Princess) Anna** and **Queen (formerly Princess) Elsa** from *Frozen*
- **Princess Nala** from the Lion King and **Princess Kiara** from *The Lion King II*
- **Princesses Adella, Alana, Andrina, Aquata, Arista and Attina** from *The Little Mermaid* and **Princess Melody** from *The Little Mermaid II*
- **President (formerly Princess) Vanellope von Schweetz** from *Wreck-it Ralph*
- **Princess Kida Nedakh** from *Atlantis the Lost Empire*
- **Princess Nancy** from *Enchanted*
- **Princess Tiger Lily** from *Peter Pan*
- **Princesses Sofia, Amber, Clio, Jun, Vivian and Hildegard** from *Sofia the First: Once Upon a Princess*, **Princess Ivy** from *Sofia the First: The Curse of Princess Ivy* and **Princesses Oona and Cora** from *Sofia the First: The Floating Palace*
- **Princesses Ting-Ting, Su and Mei** from *Mulan II*
- **Princesses Atta and Dot** from *A Bug's Life*
- **Princess Minnie Mouse of France** from *Mickey, Donald, Goofy: The Three Musketeers*
- **Princess Eilonwy of Llyr** from *The Black Cauldron*
- **Princess Dawn** from *Strange Magic*
- **Princess Elena and Isabel** from *Elena of Avalor*

Several princesses have also appears in various live-action properties

- **Princesses Audrey, Evie and Anxelin** from *Descendants*
- **Princess Chelina of Zaragoza** from *Cinderella* (2015)
- **Princess Draupadi** from *Arjun: The Warrior Prince*
- **Princess Ozma** from *Return to Oz*
- **Princess Tamina** from *Prince of Persia: The Sands of Time*
- **Princess Dejah Thoris** from *John Carter*
- **Princess Elspeth** from *Dragonslayer*
- **Princesses May Belle of Terabithia** from *Bridge to Terabithia* (note, self-appointed)
- **Princess Aida** from *Trenchcoat*
- **Princess Milli Chakravarty** from *Khoobsurat*
- **Princesses Katey and Sarah** from *A Kid in King Arthur's Court*
- **Princess Rosalinda Flore** from *Princess Protection Programme*
- **Princesses Mia Thermopolis and Palisades** from *The Princess Diaries* and **Princesses Hannah, Lorraine, Charlee, Alexandra, Aimee, Nicole, Nadia, Claudia, Nadege, Maui, Grace and Camille** from *The Princess Diaries II*
- **Princess Winnifred** from *Once Upon a Mattress*
- **[Princess Leia of Alderaan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRMFH71fDIE)** from the *Star Wars* franchise

Notably, Esmeralda was *removed* from the official lineup in 2004. Other characters have failed to make the cut for a number of reasons, usually due to their films simply being too <s>unpopular</s> niche to justify their inclusion into the official pantheon.

It's also noteworthy that several of the "princesses" aren't actually princesses at all. Mulan is married to a General, Pocahontas is the daughter of an American-Indian tribal chief and Moana is the daughter of a Polynesian Tribal chieftain.

Comment: Note that certain Princesses didn't join immediately upon their movie's release - for example, Merida was added in 2013, but Brave came out in 2012 - so it's possible that some princesses from your list (I'm specifically thinking about Anna and possibly Elsa) could become official Disney Princesses in the future.

Comment: @AdamV - The list is reasonably fluid. I suspect that Anna/Elsa will be added in 2016, along with Moana.

Comment: The only thing you need to be a princess is to have a *significant portrayal of heroism.*

Comment: Aphrodite, may be called a princess but she's not a 'bona-fide' one, what she is is a bona-fide goddess.

Comment: She is generally not considered the [daughter of Zeus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphrodite#Birth). Also the Pantheon does not and never did work like that. So even if you go with the less used mythology, that still does not bestow the title of princess on her. In fact on her wiki page you won't find the word princess used even once.

Comment: @ryan - I see your point and I'm certainly not wedded to the idea of keeping her in. I'll do a bit more research to see whether she's his daughter *in that film*.

Comment: I actually tried finding her on IMDB and the wiki for the film but they didn't mention anything about her.

Comment: @ryan - I don't think she has a speaking role.

Comment: Great answer, Richard!   You might want to also include Giselle from *Enchanted* --- she's in my answer.  She is both live action and animated (in the same film), so I'm not sure how you would categorize her.

Comment: @Praxis - I've excluded her for a reason. She's not a princess at the start of the film, nor is she one at the end. The telling line in the film is "**Morgan:** *Are you a princess?*. **Giselle:** *Not yet"*. This clearly indicates that she won't be a real princess until she marries her prince (which doesn't happen). I've also excluded Megara for the same reason. She's the heroine but she ain't a Princess

Comment: @Richard : My understanding is that being officially registered as a Disney princess can be done through avenues other than literal princess-hood (e.g. significant heroism), but fair enough.  :-)

Comment: @Praxis - The question was which princesses didn't make the cut, not which heroines.

Comment: @Richard : Ah, well that *does* make a difference. :-)

Comment: I'd argue about Jane too. She might be married to the "King of the Jungle" but that doesn't make her a Princess.

Comment: @Richard : I think whichever issues there are surrounding "King of the Jungle", they also surround "Lion King"...

Comment: @Praxis - Ah, but my issue is that her marrying the King of the Jungle would make her the Queen of the Jungle.

Comment: @Richard : Hehe, I see your point. :-)

Comment: @Richard You might want to add that it's not that Anna and Elsa "didn't make the cut", but rather were "successful enough for them to have their own franchise."

Comment: @corsiKa - I think the operative word is "yet". They'll almost certainly get added in the next few years.

Comment: @Richard that's not likely. The Disney Princess is a franchise in and of itself. Because Anna and Elsa were so runaway successful, they've instead got their own franchise, Disney Frozen. It is unlikely they'll be added to the Disney Princess franchise unless their popularity drops by a substantial amount. It's much like Tinkerbell and Disney Fairies.

Comment: @Richard To put things into perspective, the entire Disney Princess franchise was born out of the idea that girls were showing up to Disney events wearing generic princess costumes, not Disney princess costumes. Enter Disney Princess to fill that void. The number 1 selling princess costume of all time is Elsa, and the number 2 is Anna. They don't need any support in terms of merchandising.

Comment: Sofia, who is a princess via the marriage of her mother to the King, has a step-sister named Amber. Amber is definitely a princess (biologically) and is, in fact, quite a stereotypical one.

Comment: Still no comment about the linked song (link in princess Leia's name). I have to fix that !

Comment: I don't know if pings for comments survive deletion of a post, but I deleted the answer below.

Comment: @Praxis - I didn't get a ping.

Comment: If we are including the recent star wars purchase, we need to include Fox as well, which means the queen xenomorph should be on that list, and if you want to really stretch it how about a drag queen (Dr Frank N Furter from Rocky Horror)

Comment: The "Live-action" princesses from Enchanted, et al, are not included because the Disney legal team determined that it would require making payments to the actresses who played them for their Likeness Rights, and Disney decided that wasn't happening.

Comment: @VBartilucci - I've seen that said on many occasions but I've never been able to track down a quote that confirms it.

Comment: @VBartilucci - To be frank, for me the bigger concern is that Giselle isn't a princess and doesn't end up with the Prince and that the woman who ends up with the Prince is basically a bit-part

Comment: @Valorum - It's mentioned in the Wiki for Enchanted, under Marketing - "Disney had originally planned to add Giselle to the Disney Princess line-up, as was shown at a 2007 Toy Fair where the Giselle doll was featured with packaging declaring her with Disney Princess status, but decided against it when they realized they would have to pay for lifelong rights to Amy Adams' image." includes a reference to a Wall Street Journal story.

Comment: @VBartilucci - Yes, I've read it. And while (later on the page) it makes mention of an earlier interview with a guy from Disney, it doesn't actually quote him about Enchanted.

Comment: Princess Vanellope von Schweetz seems to be inducted in the new Wreck-It Ralph film, _Ralph Breaks the Internet_, going by [the trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BcYBFC6zfY).

Comment: @SQB - no official announcement has been made :-)

Comment: @Valorum - If you're including the Fox princesses, don't forget Princess Arya from Eragon.

Comment: @ibid - I'm sticking with Disney productions, not subsidiaries like 20th Century Fox

Comment: @Valorum - Yet you include Star Wars?

Comment: @ibid - For comedy value. **Nobody** is laughing about Eragon.

Comment: Why is Anna also a queen?

Comment: @EtackSxchange - Elsa abdicated at the end of the second film https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=eS8-Vyl7qRY