# Is Princess Leia a disney Princess now?

Tags: star-wars, disney-princess

I was watching this:

and it occurred to me, is Leia even classified as a Disney Princess now?

I'm aware she may not be included or merchandised in the "family" in the same way, but I'm curious as to her classification.

Comment: Technically, I don't believe she was a princess during Force Awakens, the only Disney movie she was in...but she is a princess from a franchise owned by Disney

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRMFH71fDIE

Comment: Yes. It's all part of an evil plot by Disney to expand the Princess line. They wanted Wonder Woman, too, but because the Disney execs don't really understand comic books they got confused and bought Marvel by mistake.

Comment: I feel like Disney would probably love to claim Leia as theirs, but they didn't create her  - so no.  By that metric, Princess Mononoke would be a Disney princess too, and that room would be full of corpses by the end of that video.

Comment: Disney didn't create almost any of their princesses. And San isn't really a princess of anything. She's the adoptive daughter of a god.

Comment: @phantom42 Disney did create their princesses. They wrote their stories (heavily modified older stories), animated them, and voiced them. If you are talking about the fact that they were based on old fairy tales, that seems like a pretty pedantic point. Leia, on the other hand, they had nothing to do with. As for Princess Mononoke, she was princess enough for the title, so I give her the go-ahead. I doubt wolf gods adhere to royal caste rules anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes and no, but more no than yes.

### No

"[Disney Princess](http://princess.disney.co.uk/)" is a media brand owned and operated by Disney Consumer Products. As of March 2016, there have been no indications that Princess Leia will be added to the existing lineup of princesses. There are presently no live action princess, nor are all of the princesses owned by the Disney brand part of the [existing lineup](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112664/20774), indeed [the overwhelming majority are not](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112684/20774).

### Yes

Disney certainly seem more than happy to merchandise and operate a brand of Disney related Star Wars products in their parks but they've done so for decades anyway, as part of the merchandising for their "[Star Wars: Star Tours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Tours)" rides, so it's not such a huge shift as you might think.

[image]