# What are the authoritative criteria for being a Disney Princess?

Tags: disney, disney-princess

The [official Disney Princess website](https://princess.disney.com/) currently lists fourteen princesses, expanding from the long-set twelve with the most recent addition of Anna & Elsa:

> - Tiana
> - Moana
> - Ariel
> - Mulan
> - Belle
> - Pocahontas
> - Snow White
> - Cindarella
> - Rapunzel
> - Merida
> - Jasmine
> - Aurora
> - Elsa
> - Anna

It is a factual observation that in Disney’s eponymously titled *Mulan*, Mulan wasn’t born into royalty and didn’t marry a prince, making her your basic nonroyal person. Likewise for the ancient Chinese legend as told in the poem *The Ballad of Mulan* about Hua Mulan which inspired it — not a princess.

The [Disney Princess Wiki](https://disneyprincess.fandom.com/wiki/Disney_Princess) lists some criteria but doesn’t source them well, notes caveats, and includes some suspect special exemption criteria to explain away reasons why some characters are included, for example, the criteria for “Mulan heroic deed” exemption:

> **Requirements to be a "Disney Princess"**
> Each official Disney Princess must meet the following requirements:
>
> 1. The character must have a central role in an animated Disney/Pixar film.
> 2. The character must be human, or have a humanoid appearance in the cases of Ariel and formerly Tinker Bell.
> 3. The character should not be the star of a sequel.
> 4. The character must be royal by birth, royal by marriage, or do a heroic deed in cases of Mulan.
> 5. The character's film should not have been an overwhelming success or an underwhelming failure, like solely with the case of Aurora. This explains the absence of Eilonwy and Kida.
> 6. Along with it, the character must have massive appeal and recognition towards viewers and audiences.

Is anyone aware of any time Disney themselves detailed criteria for who it considers being a part of their “Disney Princess” brand? Looking for authoritative sources only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an official list of Disney Princesses?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112663/). Specifically the "*How they were chosen*" portion of the accepted answer

Comment: According to Wreck-It-Ralph 2, Magic hands or magic hair; cursed, poisoned, or kidnapped; animals talk to them; and people assume all their problems were solved just because some big, strong man showed up.

Comment: "The character's film should not have been an overwhelming success". Wasn't *Frozen* (and most of the Disney princesses' films) an overwhelming success?

Comment: The biggest criteria is, of course, "marketability". I posit that Anna and Elsa weren't originally included in the line up because they were selling so well on their own, as part of the "Frozen" branded merchandise. As that slows down, they can be added to the "Princess" branded merchandise to continue selling. Someone like Eilonwy or Kida, despite meeting any technical criteria there might be, don't get included because the little girls the brand is marketed to don't know who they are.